# Flutter: Excessive Widget Rebuilds and Performance Issues in Screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-animation

hope you all are well.

I'm trying to create screen with a custom painter that draws a 'radar'.  The idea is that when the app open it will be just the radar displaying and then when I click a button the radar animates and then I use a stack and display 10 icon buttons randomly around the 'radar'.

I got it working where it would update and show two constant or pre programmed buttons and I used a  ValueListenableBuilder to display or not display the buttons but not rebuld the painter.

However now I introduced the actual fucntion I wanted which is using a stream builder from firebase. So I put the stream builder into the  ValueListenableBuilder. Now when I click the start button,  the icon buttons (I think these are the only rebuilding widgets) rebuild constanly. I had a Connection state waiting loading screen and that just stays and the buttons don't render, if I take it out the buttons render but constanly rebuild. In flutter dev tools when I click start the frames graph goes wild and lots of jank frames. The widget build tracker shows quite a few widgets rebuilding.

I am very out of my depth here as I am still learning and wanted to try an idea I had. I will add the two screens that are linked but please let me know what else I need to add as I really am stuck and confused. Kind of a don't know what I don't know situaion.

```
class RadarScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RadarScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.isLooking,
    required this.controller,
    required this.radius,
    required this.userList,
    required this.animation,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final ValueNotifier<bool> isLooking;
  final AnimationController controller;
  final Animation animation;
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? userList;
  final double radius;

  @override
  State<RadarScreen> createState() => _RadarScreenState();
}

class _RadarScreenState extends State<RadarScreen> {
  late ValueNotifier<bool> _isLooking;
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation _animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _isLooking = widget.isLooking;
    _controller = widget.controller;
    _animation = widget.animation;
    super.initState();
  }
....other code
```

```
StatefulBuilder(

              builder: (context, setState) {
                return Center(
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: RadarPainter(),
                    foregroundPainter: PointPainter(
                      widget.radius,
                      _animation.value,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                valueListenable: _isLooking,
                builder: (context, value, child) {
                  if (value == true) {
                    return Stack(children: [
                      for (final userData in widget.userList!)
                        Positioned(
                            left: Random().nextDouble() *
                                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 100),
                            top: Random().nextDouble() *
                                (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 100),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0, right: 50),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) {
                                        return AlertDialog(
                                          actions: [
                                            ElevatedButton(
                                                onPressed: () =>
                                                    Navigator.of(context)
                                                        .push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder: (context) =>
                                                          const CustomChatScreen(),
                                                    )),
                                                child:
                                                    const Text('Break The Ice'))
                                          ],
                                          icon: Tab(
                                              icon: Image.network(
                                                  userData['picture'])),
                                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          title: Text(userData['Name']),
                                          content: const Text(
                                              'John is a rat, Self-proclaimed connoisseur of fine cheese and expert in photobombing humans. ✨ #RatWithAttitude #CheeseIsLife'),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    );
                                  },
                                  icon: const Icon(Icons.person),
                                  label: Text('Test'),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ))
                    ]);
                  }else{
                    return const Center();
                  }
                })
```

Then here is the code for the parent widget which is a stack and is meant to control the valuelistner

```
ValueNotifier<bool> isLooking = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  late AnimationController controller;
  int stackIndex = 0;

  final _radius = 190.0;
  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> fetchUserData() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').get();
    return snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
  }

  late Animation<double> animation;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 8),
    );
    Tween<double> rotationTween = Tween(begin: -math.pi, end: math.pi);

    animation = rotationTween.animate(controller)
      ..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      })
      ..addStatusListener((status) {
        if (status == AnimationStatus.completed) {
          controller.repeat();
        } else if (status == AnimationStatus.dismissed) {
          controller.forward();
        }
      });
  }
....other code
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (isLooking.value == true) {
                      controller.stop();

                      setState(() {
                        isLooking.value = false;
                      });
                    } else {
                      controller.forward();

                      setState(() {
                        isLooking.value = true;
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  label: !isLooking.value
                      ? const Text('Start Searching')
                      : const Text('Stop Searching'),
                  icon: !isLooking.value
                      ? const Icon(Icons.search)
                      : const Icon(Icons.search_off),
                ),
...other code
FutureBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                  future: fetchUserData(), // Fetch data only once
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
                      );
                    } else {
                      final userList = snapshot.data;
                      return RadarScreen(
                        isLooking: isLooking,
                        animation: animation,
                        radius: _radius,
                        controller: controller,
                        userList: userList,
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

I tried changing from a stream builder to a future builder hoping it would only get data once but the issue still persists.

I also originally had the stream/future builder in the 'Radar Screen' and not the 'holder Screen' but it's the exact same issue.

Edit: I thought a video might help: [Video](https://imgur.com/a/hJsJSjF)

Comment: Why do you pass `animation` in a constructor. StatefulWidget is persistent with it's element, maybe passing `animation` in the constructor causing it to rebuild.

Comment: Have you tried adding a key to the future/stream builder?

Comment: Hey, @ermekk do you mean passing the animation from holder screen to radar screen? I did it because the holder screen had the logic and controlled it, the radar screen doesn't have any logic. The reason I did this was because of the stack, I needed to have scaffold for the respective screens in the stack and then because the scaffold was in the holder screen that's where the floating action button is, so i made the logic in the holder screen for the floating action button to use

Comment: @ermekk with regards to the key. What do you recommend I do, I'm not very strong with using keys. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I would pass logic result(int, string, list etc) instead of `animation` object, never seen that `animation` is passed like that. But not sure it would help.

Comment: `StreamBuilder(key: ValueKey(isLooking), ...other)` for example. So it'll rebuild if only `isLooking` was changed. And if some parent widgets getting rebuilt, it'll as well.

Comment: It's interesting task, to discuss it more you can reach me at [telegram](https://t.me/alepps)